# I want to create C# Web App which can create excel report from different SQL database only in one click.is there any good suggestion?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I want to create C# Web App which can create excel report from different SQL database only in one click.is there any good suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this using a framework called ClosedXml.

[ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

You didn't specific which type of web app. If this is MVC, it should be a matter of wiring an HTML button to call an MVC controller, which does the query and compilation of data. See the following code for manipulating the spreadsheet.

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

EDIT: I'm a jerk and didn't see your asp.net-mvc tag. The above should stand as a solution.

Comment: thanks for suggestion,i will try this @Will McCullough